# How to append an array in URL request type GET in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, urlrequest

I am using Xcode7.3 with Swift2.2.

I want to append an Array in url request.For example my array like
`[“jeevan”,”jeejo”]`. I want to append this array with key(arrayKey) in url request like  must be the following pattern

```
https://api.com/pre/ws/ch/roo?arrayKey=jeevan%2Cjeejo
```

How to solve this issue? Please help me

Answer (score 3):

You need to use encode your URL instead of join `Array` with separator, but if you want to merge Array with `URL` you can try like this.

```
let str = ["jeevan","jeejo"]
let join = str.joinWithSeparator("%2C")
let url = "https://api.com/pre/ws/ch/roo?arrayKey=\(join)"
```

If you want to encode url encode this way.

```
let str = ["jeevan","jeejo"]
let join = str.joinWithSeparator(",") 
let url = "https://api.com/pre/ws/ch/roo?arrayKey=\(join)"
let encoded = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())
```

**Note :** The reason I have used `,` is because `%2C` is encode for `,` you can confirm it here on [W3School URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Answer (score 0):

easy solution can be like this

```
var URIString = ""

for item in array {
    URIString +=\(item)%2C
}
```

after subtract last 3 characters and make URL string

Answer (score 0):

Simple code like this

```
var array: [String] = ["jeevan","jeejo"]

var myString = ""

for i in 0..<array.count {
   myString += array[i]
   if (i+1)<array.count { mystring+="%2C" }
}
```

Can give you result like this:

> jeevan%2Cjeejo